# Python - Superimpose 2 plots in subplot with matplotlib by using alpha channel

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, alpha

I would like to superimpose 2 plots in one plot by using "alpha channel".
I try to get the contour of the right figure on plot of left:

[image]

My code is :

```
plt.close()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)

plt.tight_layout(pad=0.05, w_pad=0.001, h_pad=2.0)
ax1 = plt.subplot(131) # creates first axis
ax1.set_xticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
ax1.set_yticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
ax1.tick_params(labelsize=8) 
i1 = ax1.imshow(U,cmap='hot',extent=(X.min(),2000,Y.min(),2000), vmin=U.min(), vmax=U.max())
cb1=plt.colorbar(i1,ax=ax1,ticks=[U.min(),(U.min()+U.max())/2., U.max()],fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,format='%.2f')
cb1.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)

ax1.set_title("$ \mathrm{Ux_{mes} \/ (pix)}$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2 = plt.subplot(132) # creates second axis
ax2.set_xticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
ax2.set_yticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
i2=ax2.imshow(UU,cmap='hot',extent=(X.min(),2000,Y.min(),2000), vmin=U.min(), vmax=U.max())
ax2.set_title("$\mathrm{Ux_{cal} \/ (pix)}$", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_xticklabels([])
ax2.set_yticklabels([])
cb2=plt.colorbar(i2,ax=ax2,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[U.min(),(U.min()+U.max())/2.,U.max()],format='%.2f')
cb2.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)

ax3 = plt.subplot(133) # creates first axis
ax3.set_xticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
ax3.set_yticks([0,2000,500,1000,1500])
i3 = ax3.imshow(resU,cmap='hot',extent=(X.min(),2000,Y.min(),2000))
ax3.set_title("$\mathrm{\mid Ux_{mes} - Ux_{cal} \mid \/ (pix)}$ ", y=1.05, fontsize=12)
cb3=plt.colorbar(i3,ax=ax3,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04,ticks=[resU.min(), (resU.min()+resU.max())/2.,resU.max()],format='%.2f')
ax3.set_xticklabels([])
ax3.set_yticklabels([])
cb3.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
plt.gcf().tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I use the command below to get the contour and to add it :

```
[masquey,masquey] = np.gradient(masquey)
plt.imshow(masquey2,cmap='hot',alpha=0.1)
```

but it doesnt work... i get that :

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you want, it should work if you simply re-use ax1 instead of using ax3.  For example, use ax1.imshow(resU,cmap='hot',extent=(X.min(),2000,Y.min(),2000))

Comment: yep and i need only the contour of the third plot to superimpose on it...i think i should use alpha channel but doesn t work...

Comment: Does adding "alpha=0.5" to the end of the arguments do anything? What is "doesn't work"?

Comment: It would help us if you follow advice here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, to me, exactly clear what you want, but here is an example with superimposed `imshow` plots.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
rand1=np.random.random((2000,500))
ax1 = plt.subplot(131) 
ax1.imshow(rand1)
box=np.zeros_like(rand1)
box[100:400,100:400]=1
ax1.imshow(box,cmap='Greys',alpha=0.6)
```

[image]

Perhaps you need to make sure you have the right subplot selected.

e.g.

```
ax3 = plt.subplot(131) for your third plot.
```

Comment: thanks for your help! it s exactly what i try to do but when i do that i got the right colorbar (so seems to be ok) but the field is quite uniform...dont understand the mistake...

Comment: It s ok i forgot the "extent" term that s why it was uniform.. :) thanks ;)